# How to configure a mod_rewrite to check both direct IP and proxy IP?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure our wordpress .htaccess file so that it blocks access to the wordpress wp-login.php and admin pages unless the client originates from within our networks.

The dev environment is directly accessible, but production is behind a proxy, so to keep things simple I wanted to configure one set of rules that would apply in either case.

I have configured the below set of rules, which based on my research, should be working:

```
#only allow use of wp-login or wp-admin from users inside
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.(1|2|3|4)\.[0-9]{1,3}$            [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^192\.168\.(1|2|3|4)\.[0-9]{1,3}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

However, for some reason the [OR] between the REMOTE_ADDR and the X-FORWARDED-FOR appears to be ignored, causing the pages to be blocked in all cases.

Am I missing something?

Edit:  I shouldn't have had the OR condition to begin with.  Apparently my brain had insufficient coffee to compute basic binary operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your clients go through a proxy or through a direct connection. Since you will block them if EITHER isn't matching, you'll most likely block them all. Someone coming via a local proxy should be getting through. I wouldn't do the XFF-stuff in the .htacces, use [mod_remoteip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) if possible, and only trust your own proxies, because that header can be easily spoofed by the client.

Additionally, the $ in the wp-admin line means it won't match wp-admin/edit.php. Consider aswell that WP ajax requests go through wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, and you might need those.